# Do there exist $m,n$ such that $6 = 2(2m+1)^2/(2n+1)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Can the two numbers $n$ and $m$ exists such that

$$6=\frac{2(2m+1)^2}{(2n+1)^2}$$

where $\gcd(m,n) = 1$?

Comment: Notice that this would imply that $3=(\frac{a}{b})^2$ for some integers $a$ and $b$. Is this possible?

Comment: This would imply square root of 3 is rational.

Comment: @fleablood Yeah, this. But thats a piece of my demonstation, i have demonstrated (at least i hope) that n and m must be both odd. So now if there is a criteria that let me say "n and m does not exists" i will demonstarte that sqrt3 is irrational.

Comment: @Mathematician42 exactly.

Comment: You can show that $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational in exactly the same fashion as for $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Advice:  in context of asking a question, you should indicate you know the answer and you goal is deminstrating.  Also, I don't know that show a and b must be odd helps.  In fact I think it makes it harder.

Comment: Does "n, m primes between them" mean relatively prime or "in lowest terms"?

Comment: How have you demonstrated n and m must both be odd?  If n and me are odd then (2m + 1)^2 and and (2n+1)^2 are divisible by 4.  how does that help?

Comment: @fleablood  ...They Cannot be both even for sure so... ...$3n^2=m^2$... ....if $n$ was even also $n^2$ is and also $3n^2$ BUT if $n$ was even $m$ must be odd and also $m^2$ thats absurd because we have in this situation even=odd... ...now if $n$ was odd $3n^2$ is odd too and $m^2$ MUST be odd too, so the only possible case is $(n,m)odd$...    ...is this right?

Comment: YOu aren't being clear whether you are talking about n,m in (2m+1)^2 and (2n+1)^2 being even or odd or about n and m in n^2/m^2 being even or odd.

Comment: @fleablod im talking about them in the formula $sqrt(3)=\frac{m}{n}$ sorry for the imprecistation.

Comment: $$(2m + 1)^2 = 4m^2 + 4m + 1$$ $$(2n + 1)^2 = 2n^2 + 2m + 1$$ $$\therefore 6 = \frac{\require{cancel}\cancel{2}(4m^2 + 4m + 1)}{\cancel{2}(n^2 + n + 1/2} = \frac{4m(m + 1) + 1}{n(n + 1) + 1/2}$$ Obviously if you convert the denominator to an improper fraction, it cycles, so this method does not work....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to prove that without using the fact that $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational.

No problem.

Suppose that you have $3=\dfrac {(2m+1)^2}{(2n+1)^2}$.

Then $(2m+1)^2=3(2n+1)^2$.

That is, $4m^2+4m+1=12n^2+12n+3$.

So $4m^2+4m-12n^2-12n=2$ so the left hand side is divisible by $4$ but the right hand side is not, so such $m,n$ do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

By the comments above, it suffices to show that $\sqrt{3}$ is not a rational number. We proceed by contradiction. So suppose that $\sqrt{3}=\frac{a}{b}$ with $a,b$ integers such that $\text{gcd}(a,b)=1$. (We may assume this without loss of generality). Then $3=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$, hence $3a^2=b^2$. It follows that $3\mid b^2$ and thus that $3\mid b$. Thus we can write $b=3k$ for some integer $k$. Thus $3a^2=9k^2$, thus $a^2=3k^2$. In the same fashion we conclude that $3\mid a$, thus we may write $a=3l$ for some $l$. But then $\text{gcd}(a,b)\geq 3$ contrary to our assumption. Thus we conclude that $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational.

Let me give you an alternative proof. Notice that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is given by $x^2-3$. Indeed, clearly $\sqrt{3}$ is a root of this polynomial and by the criterium of Eisenstein, we see that this polynomial is irreducible. It follows that the extension degree  $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=2$. Thus $\left\{1,\sqrt{3}\right\}$ forms a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, it follows that $\sqrt{3}\notin \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yeah, but im trying to give another alternative proof, i dont know if its correct, lets say $gcd(n,m)=1$, now, i want to demonstrate that n and m are both odd. They Cannot be both even for sure so...  ...$3n^2=m^2$...  ....if $n$ was even also $n^2$ is and also $3n^2$ BUT if $n$ was even $m$ must be odd and also $m^2$ thats absurd. We have in this situation even=odd...    ...now if $n$ was odd $3n^2$ is odd too and $m^2$ MUST be odd too, so the only possible case is $(n,m) odd$. Now considering that if there is no possibilities to have $2\cdot3=\frac{2m^2}{n^2}$ i have finished. Im wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your first "so". You say that $3n^2=m^2$, why? Don't you start with $3=\frac{(2m+1)^2}{(2n+1)^2}$?

Comment: i use $3n^2=m^2$ for proof that $n$ and $m$ must be both odd. Let's say we start with $3=\frac{m^2}{n^2}$ but $m$ and $n$ are both odd and $gcd(m,n)=1$.

Comment: Ah ok, yes that is correct. But the proof of the remaining case is the same as the one I gave above.

Comment: @OsvaldoPaniccia: it seems to me that you want to prove $\sqrt 3$ is irrational by proving that $\sqrt 3$ is irrational.

Comment: @TonyK no, by trying to do that and fail at it.